# android async task usage in depending sequence of tasks

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

My App contains a function that takes time to load ( parsing files).
THe function is called at multiple user case, i.e. from multiple user triggered condition.
Besides, it is called when onCreate is called.

In simple word, the flow is:

1. User click/OnCreate trigger
2. Function to parse file
3. Post to windows
4. Other postprocessing

I hope the user can click cancel to stop parsing files.

I tried to use asynctask. I know I can put the function to onPostExecute.
But I assume onPostExecute is just for dismiss progress dialog. Or I have to move a lot of codes ( for different cases) to it. Not a good idea.

I do not suppose user to do anything during parsing files.

So, what is the best way to do so? Despite I know it is not good, I think i have to occupy the UI thread.

In simple word, I want to wait for "parsing files", but i do not want to occupy the UI thread, so user can click cancel.

update:
I tried. however, there is a problem:
I use asynctask. I called:

```
mTask = new YourAsyncTask().execute();
YourAsyncTask.get();  // this force to wait for YourAsyncTask to return.
DoSomethingBaseOnAsyncTaskResult();
```

YourAsyncTask.get() hold the UI thread. So, there is not loading dialog, and user cannot click cancel from the dialog. It seems I have to move every line after

```
mTask = new YourAsyncTask().execute();
```

to

```
OnPostExecute()
```

which i did not prefer to do so because DoSomethingBaseOnAsyncTaskResult() can be very different based on the return result. or else, it becomes do everything in YourAsyncTask()

Answer (score 0):

**In order to use the AsyncTask API, one has to follow the steps described below:**

1. Create a class which extends AsyncTask.
2. Fill in the generic types available as generics in the class for:

   - the task execution array parameters
   - progress array parameters
   - result array parameters
3. Implement the method doInBackground(Parameters... parameters). This
   method must execute the job which is supposed to be quite demanding.
4. Optionally, one can implement methods for:

   - cancelling the task - onCancelled(...)
   - executing tasks before the demanding task - onPreExecute(...)
   - reporting progress - onProgressUpdate(...)
   - executing activities after the demanding task is finished
     -onPostExecute(...).